# "increment or decrement to bring into range"

Tags: synonyms, terminology, range-inclusion

I'm looking for a (preferably single) word for "increment or decrement to bring into range", with particular emphasis on 'bring into range'.

'Reconcile' or '[limit](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4826/how-can-i-deliver-the-meaning-of-within-a-specified-range?rq=1)' are not bad as far as target (range) is concerned. The musical term 'modulation' expresses the action but doesn't quite reach the biscuit tin as far as target (range) is concerned.

Imagine a number (could represent a note in an octave) which is either too high or low to fit into a given range (the acoustic range, say, of an instrument's finger- or keyboard) and so would have to be tonally adjusted (modulated up or down by an octave) in order to be playable.

Now, taking away the musical connotations, is there another word with more general application?

Comment: *tune*, *adjust*.

Comment: Where does that leave excrement, I wonder?

Comment: Crap comment, dude. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps 'calibrate' would fit the bill? I would use it with the sense of adjusting a device in order to bring some metric to within a given range.

> 3
>   :  to standardize (as a measuring instrument) by determining the deviation from a standard so as to ascertain the proper correction factors

Answer (score 1):

My background is archery, so my association here is to ***[aim](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aim)***.

> verb
>
> 1. [WITH OBJECT] Point or direct (a weapon or camera) at a target:
>    aim the camcorder at some suitable object
>    [NO OBJECT]: aim for the middle of the target

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aim

Answer (score 1):

Music - the word is **transpose**.  (not modulate)

> In music transposition refers to the process, or operation, of moving
>   a collection of notes (pitches or pitch classes) up or down in pitch
>   by a constant interval.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_(music))

Mathematics - the word is **normalize**.

> transitive verb
>
> 1
>
> :  to make conform to or reduce to a norm or standard
>
> 2
>
> :  to make normal (as by a transformation of variables)
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/normalize)

Answer (score 0):

[Clamp](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_clamp) (from the data visualization domain, so not widely known).